# Deployment screen hangs

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment

I'm trying to deploy the latest version of my chat bot, but when I try to deploy (or manage deployments) I get a loading icon and the text `Loading Deployment...`

Comment: Have you tried to delete cache and cookies? Have you review if you can reproduce the issue in another project? or with a different Browser? Or check if it works in a different network? If that doesn't it, you should be able to submit an issue tracker by following the steps in this [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback).

Comment: I've tried it on Safari - same issue.

Comment: Cleared cookies - same issue.

Comment: Different network - same issue.

Comment: Turns out someone had the same issue in January. It has been assigned P2, but no moment thus far...

Comment: If you have a Workspace account you can also tried to open a case with them, here are the [steps.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213)

They might be able to speed up the process of reporting the issue.

Comment: In the end, I just gave up and rebuilt the project. So annoying that it didn't even give me an error message...